# C# How to make a simple UDP server

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

Can I make UDP server and client using `UdpClient` class?
And I need to send an Image from the server to all Clients.
Can some show me a code sample. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 13):

Check out the following sample codes:

[Listener](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/92846ccb-fad3-469a-baf7-bb153ce2d82b/)

[Simple UDP Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx)

Comment: Isnt there a way using UdpClient class instead of using Socket class to establish a server ?

Comment: I am curious about what is the advantage of doing that?

Comment: If you need to make a SERVER then you need to open socket to accept incoming requests from the CLIENT. I am not aware of a way to connect a client to a client, peer-to-peer connections are made using socket listener on both ends (as far as I know)

Answer (score 2):

[`System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is tricky.  Some of the constructors specify the local end point, while others specify the remote end point.  To establish two way communication, use a constructor that specifies the local end point.

Specify the default remote end point with `Connect`, or use a `Send`/`BeginSend` overload that specifies the remote end point.