# How do I make a UDP Server in C#?

Tags: c#, udp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# How to make a simple UDP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108100/c-sharp-how-to-make-a-simple-udp-server)

I want to make a UDP server in C#. How do I do that? How can I customize which port it listens on (namely 1212)?

Comment: This article might help you: - [A Simple Multi-threaded TCP/UDP Server and Client V2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/patricklam/simpletcpudpserverclientpl211222005040054am/simpletcpudpserverclientpl2.aspx)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is a [sample in C#](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/UdpServerSample.htm):

```
/*
C# Network Programming 
by Richard Blum

Publisher: Sybex 
ISBN: 0782141765
*/
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class UdpSrvrSample
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      byte[] data = new byte[1024];
      IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
      UdpClient newsock = new UdpClient(ipep);

      Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");

      IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

      data = newsock.Receive(ref sender);

      Console.WriteLine("Message received from {0}:", sender.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));

      string welcome = "Welcome to my test server";
      data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
      newsock.Send(data, data.Length, sender);

      while(true)
      {
         data = newsock.Receive(ref sender);

         Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
         newsock.Send(data, data.Length, sender);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: if you wan't freezing your winform ui, you can use Threading class. Thread th = new  Thread th = new Thread(() => {
                UDPServerInitAndListen();
  
            });
            th.IsBackground = true;
            th.Start();