# Exception in Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

i have an exception in my application that i'm confused of

i do have an method which is

```
private void ListenForClients()
    {
        UdpClient client;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                client = oUdpClient;
                Remote_EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                client.Receive(ref Remote_EndPoint);
                client.Connect(Remote_EndPoint);
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                client = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

the error i get is that

> Once the socket has been disconnected, you can only reconnect again
>   asynchronously, and only to a different EndPoint.  BeginConnect must
>   be called on a thread that won't exit until the operation has been
>   completed.

from that line

> client.Connect(Remote_EndPoint);

and i got other error when i trace it from

> Remote_EndPoint.Address.ScopeID

which is

> 'Remote_EndPoint.Address.ScopeId' threw an exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'

so what is the solution for that exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but you're setting up this UdpClient as a listener, right?

There's no need to use the [Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4w4cta7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method (which is used by UdpClient objects acting as emitters to identify a remote receptor); Listener mode is set as soon as you identify a local endpoint.

UDP doesn't establish a connection per se (that's a characteristic of its cousin, the TCP prococol) - thus, the error message is misleading; there is no such a thing as a disconnected UDP socket.

This post may be of some help to you:

[C# How to make a simple UDP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108100/c-sharp-how-to-make-a-simple-udp-server)

Comment: actually i use UdpClient as listener and sender too to receive packets from a gps device and to send acknowledge back to the device again so i need Connect method so what is the situation here