# how to find there is no packet UDP client have?

Tags: c#, udp, udpclient

I am using Udpclient to fetch data from my punchin machine and now i want to check if there is any data in variable **receivedResults** and if there is any data then want to run the code after **Type thisType = obj.GetType()** and if there is not any data in **receivedResults** then don't  but don't know how to check this **receivedResults** have data or not.Anyone please tell me how can i do it.

```
    List<MachineData> lstMachineData = new List<MachineData>();
    UdpClient udpServer=new UdpClient (7005);
    while (true)
    {
    var receivedResults = await udpServer.ReceiveAsync();
    byte[] data = new byte[68];
    data = receivedResults.Buffer;
    MachineData objMachineData = new MachineData();
    lstMachineData.Add(objMachineData);

    Type thisType = obj.GetType();
    MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("MethodName");
    MachineData[] userParameters = new MachineData[lstMachineData.Count()];
    for (int i = 0; i <= lstMachineData.Count();i++ )
    {
    userParameters[i] = lstMachineData[i];
    }
    theMethod.Invoke(obj, userParameters);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# How to make a simple UDP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108100/c-sharp-how-to-make-a-simple-udp-server)

Comment: What do you mean by "no data"? You just received a UDP packet so there is *always* data in the buffer.